# If Statement And Statement is not equal to

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to say that:

```
If Statement1 And Statement2 are not empty Then 
Do this
```

My code looks like this:

```
  If Worksheets("Example").Cells(1 + regelnr, 2) And Worksheets("Example").Cells(1 + regelnr, 3) <> "" Then
```

However when debugging it goes into this statement when both cells are empty, and I could not find the mistake that I make here?

Any suggestions?

Comment: except languages like cobol, you can't say "if a or b or c = X" to check a = X or b = X or c = X, you have to do "if a = X or b = X or c = X".
It's a bit longer but safer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
 If((Worksheets("Example").Cells(1 + regelnr, 2) <> ""  And
 (Worksheets("Example").Cells(1 + regelnr, 3) <> ""))) Then
```

In your case it's like: IF (A AND B not equal) THEN
But the solution would be: IF ((A not equal) AND (B not equal)) THEN